# How to get user's default search engine on iOS and Android?

Tags: javascript, android, ios

Can I get users's default Search Engine on iOS and Android?

I heard the followings:

`window.getSearchEngine();`

but, it doesn't work.

Someone,pls help me...........

Answer (score 0):

try this code

I haven't yet been able to make the `setSearchEngine()` function work because for some reason I don't have permission to do so (i.e., `canSetSearchEngine()` returns false).

I know the Yahoo code works so it appears that it must be possible to do. I wonder if the js file has to be hosted on a whitelisted domain related to the selected search engine. IOW - perhaps only js code served from a yahoo, google, or bing domain has permission to call the `setSearchEngine()` function.

```
window.canSetSearchEngine() 
window.getSearchEngine() 
window.setSearchEngine(string)
```

Comment: Is that answer copied from [*Set Default Search Engine with Javascript on iOS*](https://jonathanstark.com/blog/set-default-search-engine-with-javascript-on-ios)? If so, you'd better give credit with clearly marked attribution and a link to the original.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Could you please show me how to add my domain to a whitelist of search engines??